# Is it true that any Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ with finite Lebesgue measure could be 'bounded' by an closed interval?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $B$ be any Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ with finite Lebesgue measure, could we say that: there exists a closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $\mu(B\cap([a,b])^\complement)\leq\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$.
I think we could approximate $B$ by using the finite union of the disjoint interval to achieve it. But I don't want this approach, are there any ways to prove the statement by a direct contradiction?

Comment: Are you trying to show "there exists a closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $\mu(B\cap([a,b])^\complement)\leq\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$"? You might want to consider $[-n,n]$ for positive integer $n$ and then think about what happens when you increase $n$.  Or are you trying to show that there is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ with finite Lebesgue measure which cannot be 'bounded' by any closed interval (assuming $(-\infty,\infty)$ does not count as an interval)?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I got it.